# Android Xamarin no WebView in Android.Widget

Tags: c#, android, webview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to add a Vebview to my app in Xamarin, I made a .axml with a webview in it

axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LocalWebView" />
```

But when I open MainActivity.cs and try to add line:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Kaamera);
WebView WV = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
```

I get 2 errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebView' could not be found
>   (are           you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   [Path to MainActivity.cs]   54  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression   Stat
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebView' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Path to
>   MainActivity.cs]  Active

Comment: add `using Android.Webkit;` ?

Comment: hey man, i think you shouldn't ask such questions here, better go read some C# book

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Webview, you need to add the following lines to the start of yout code.

```
using Android.Webkit;
```